# How to deploy netbeans app in MS azure

Tags: azure, netbeans, deployment

I made this java project in netbeans (it has a gui and uses files serialization) I have searched in the web for ways to deploy netbeans applications on azure however it seems that only eclipse has that feature. Thus, I am wondering if there is any way or method to deploy a netbeans application on MS Azure?

Comment: I am wondering what are trying to do? Java application whether using Eclipse or NetBeans is after all Java Application. If it's an web application, then it will need Web App server for Java like Tomcat etc Or otherwise JRE to run. Java is not default supported on azure websites, I guess you are using VirtualMachine on azure to deploy? please explain the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides a [plugin](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/) for Eclipse for packaging Java applications for deployment as Windows Azure cloud services. This plugin is not available for Netbeans.

An alternative would be to deploy to a Windows Azure virtual machine instead of a cloud service. See instructions at [How to run a Java application server on a virtual machine](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/tutorials/tomcat-on-a-virtual-machine/).

Another alternative would be to use a third-party tool such as [Cloudify for Azure](http://www.gigaspaces.com/azure).

Answer (score 0):

You can only create Cloud Service via the Eclipse [enter link description here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/) or via MS VS.

But you can still use NetBean to develop your application and use Eclipse/VS to manage your Cloud Service package.  The package will contain the app server, its configuration and your wars/ears.

To make you life easier, you can update your Cloud Service package to download the application archive (and the app server and its configuration) from blob storage.  This way no need to create a new complete package when the app is updated, you only need to upload the new war/ear and restart the instances.  This will greatly increase your development efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in 3 steps
1) update your netbeans to version 7.4 and above
2) push you project to github repository
3)publish your web app from the github repository you just updated.